# AIR application doesn't show custom icons

Tags: actionscript-3, icons, air

I have an AIR app (ActionScript only) that I build with Flash Builder 4. In the application descriptor I define the icons like that:

```
<icon>
    <image16x16>icon-16.png</image16x16>
    <image32x32>icon-32.png</image32x32>
    <image48x48>icon-48.png</image48x48>
    <image128x128>icon-128.png</image128x128>
</icon>
```

and when compiling I add those icons to the ressources to export.

After installation, the MyApplication.exe file displays my custom icon. However - the taskbar shows the normal AIR icon and if I open a Native Window then the top left icon also displays the normal AIR icon.

What else do I have to change?

I build with AIR 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the XML block for the icons isn't commented out in the application descriptor file. Flash Builder uses a template for the descriptor that has example elements commented out. It is easy not to notice this when you enter the paths for your icons.